# VSCode: Unable to set breakpoint outside initial launch module

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, parsoid

I have installed the node project `Parsoid` from its [source repo](https://github.com/wikimedia/parsoid).

I opened the project root dir with VSCode then added a basic passthru `config.yaml`:

```
worker_heartbeat_timeout: 300000

logging:
    level: debug

services:
  - module: lib/index.js
    entrypoint: apiServiceWorker
    conf:

        # Configure Parsoid to point to your MediaWiki instances.
        mwApis:
        - # This is the only required parameter,
          # the URL of you MediaWiki API endpoint.
          uri: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'
          domain: 'en.wikipedia.org'  # optional
```

I can run the app with:

```
http://localhost:8000/en.wikipedia.org/v3/page/html/Apple
```

I am now ready to inspect the code with the debugger. 
I add this `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/server.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I launch with the debugger, the breakpoint I added to `bin/server.js` is recognized. However, anything outside this dir is ignored (stating that it can't verify the other breakpoints).

[image: Only initial launch module has its breakpoint bounded.]

These breakpoints are set but not bounded. What should I modify in my config file to get them bounded?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I also trying setting `"outFiles": [ "${workspaceFolder}/bin/**/*.js", "${workspaceFolder}/lib/**/*.js" ]` but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: I also wanted to add that I migrated this project from WebStorm and never experienced any problems with unrecognized breakpoints using WebStorm. So I am pretty sure it's a config step I am missing with VSCode.